# Supremums norm on the open unit ball

Tags: normed-spaces

Is it correct to say that for a continues function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ for the supremums norm:

$$||f||_{L^{\infty}(\partial B)} \leq ||f||_{L^{\infty}(B)}.$$

That it how is the supremums norm defined? If $f$ attains it's maximum on the boundary it will never reach on the open unit ball, does this mean the equality doesn't hold? And how about if $f$ is not continues?

Comment: @user251257 I edited the question, before it did not make sense, of course.

Comment: that's is true, as long as $f$ is continuous on the closure of $B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $f$ is continuous, then it holds. If the maximum is attained for $x \in \partial B$, then you have for $x_n \in B, x_n \to x$ that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$, therefor the value $f(x)$ can be approximated to arbitrary precision:

Remember: the $\infty$-Norm is defined by the supremum, not maximum.